# Error installing Pycharm 4.0.4 Pro in Fedora 21

Tags: python, pycharm, fedora

I am very new to using a linux system, I am getting the ERROR while installing PyCharm but unable to sort it out. If possible please help.

```
[ace139@localhost pycharm-4.0.4]$ cd bin
[ace139@localhost bin]$ ls
fsnotifier       inspect.sh              log.xml              pycharm.sh
fsnotifier64     libyjpagent-linux64.so  pycharm64.vmoptions  pycharm.vmoptions
idea.properties  libyjpagent-linux.so    pycharm.png
[ace139@localhost bin]$ ./pycharm.sh
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
[    200]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - No valid license found 
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:115)
    at com.intellij.ide.a.g.bb.a(bb.java:107)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.start(MainImpl.java:47)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:105)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:91)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[    201]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - PyCharm 4.0.4  Build #PY-139.1001 
[    201]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - JDK: 1.8.0_31 
[    202]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
[    202]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
[    202]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - OS: Linux
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an article dealing with this problem. http://oonlab.com/fix-install-pycharm-fedora-21.onto/

**TLDR:**

```
sudo dnf install java-1.8.0-openjdk
```

Tested by myself on Fedora 21 and PyCharm 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a backup of ~./.PyCharm40 and remove that directory.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue, try

```
yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel
```

this will fix your problem